# What and where are the required permissions to republish existing VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

A year ago I published a Visual Studio Code extension with `vsce`.  I wish to publish an update, but lost the old token.  I created a new one, but have not been able to find the right combination of permissions to republish.

Without supplying a new token, I get:

`> vsce publish
ERROR  Failed request: (401)`

Using the new token with `Full access` scope on `All accessible organizations` or with the documented Marketplace scopes, I get:

`> vsce publish -p newtoken
ERROR  Access Denied: xxx needs the following permission(s) on the resource /aaa/bbb to perform this action: Make changes to, share, or view certificate of an existing extension`

What have I missed in setting up permissions to republish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arg.  I should have known once I took the time to post a question I'd figure out the problem.  Back story: After adopting Azure AD, there was great confusion among developers here between Office 365 accounts and Microsoft accounts--because we had been advised to use the same email address for both.

Long story short, the problem was I was attempting to publish using a token from my Office 365 account, when the extension was originally published under my Microsoft account.  It was long enough ago that I didn't remember that.  I also gave my O365 account access to the organization owned by my Microsoft account, so I could conveniently access various resources with either one.

I created a new token under my Microsoft account, and boom, publish succeeded.